# Disappears \ from db value

Tags: php, mysql

I want to save **XO/YEr\fae?3** in a mysql table.while inserting this value \ disappears and only saved **XO/YErfae?3**.Is it possible to insert \ in database?Please help

Comment: Learn to use [**prepared statements**](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nLinqtCfhKY) with either [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli).

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Its because characters after backslash are escaped by the PHP interpreter.

You can replace your code with the following :

```
XO/YEr\\fae?3
```